# How do you say parrying a sword by slashing your sword on that sword?

Tags: word-request

How do you say parrying a sword by slashing your sword on that sword? You know you can block a sword attack by blocking the slash with your swinging your sword at it. Is there a particular word for blocking a sword attack with a sword attack?

Comment: The word I'd use is "parry"  but you already know that.  Is there a term that you use in your language? Failing that, can you give an example sentence with a blank.

Comment: Can you find an example, maybe a picture or a video, of someone doing this?  In my experience as a fencer, this isn't something people do in real swordfighting, so there is not likely to be a term for it.

Comment: @stangdon - Here's a video  https://youtu.be/IkDDBL7jNew?t=147  I suspect that in real battles there was a lot of sword-to-sword contact - you're fighting to kill or die.

Comment: How else would you parry the attack? Once must be careful not to over-explain things, such as "cutting the grass with a lawnmower" and "flying to Moscow in an aeroplane" etc. lest people conclude that you think they are stupid.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica That just looks like parrying to me, not "slashing at the opponent's sword".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Parry" is the correct term to for defensive move against a fencing attack. However, I wouldn't say it is widely used outside the sport.

If you're looking for an informal, everyday term for the swords hitting together I would say that the two swords "**clashed**". The word '*clash*' literally means to collide with a loud, harsh, usually metallic noise, and through use linked with sword fights it has also come to also mean any kind of fight.